# Call class method with argument from another class method

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, class-method, method-call

In my code file **MyItemVC.swift** I have defined the following class and method:

```
class MyItemVC: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

var timer = NSTimer()

    func cycleTimer(toggleOn: Bool) {
        if toggleOn == true {
            // Timer calls the replaceItem method every 3 seconds
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, selector: Selector("replaceItem"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        } else {
            timer.invalidate() // stop the timer
        }
    }
}
```

Elsewhere in this class, I call cycleTimer(true) to start the timer and cycleTimer(false) to stop it.

Now, I also want to use the usual methods in my **AppDelegate.swift** code file to start and stop the timer when the app moves from active to inactive state. But I'm having trouble calling the cycleTimer method from that class.

I found an answer on Stack Overflow that suggested I could call it like this:

```
func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {

    MyItemVC.cycleTimer()
}
```

But I also need to pass in an argument. So I tried calling it like this:

```
func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {

    MyItemVC.cycleTimer(true)
}
```

But I got this error:

> Cannot invoke 'cycleTimer' with an argument list of type '(Bool)'

How can I call this method from the AppDelegate methods while passing in an argument?

Thanks for the help. I realize this must be a very basic question but I'm new to programming and trying to teach myself using Swift. An answer using Swift rather than Obj-C would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use class function to be able to use it this way.

```
class func cycleTimer(toggleOn: Bool) {
```

However, I'm not sure about thread safety.

Comment: After making that change, I ran into some related problems when trying to call other instance methods from within cycleTimer. But I tested a simpler example using your answer and it worked correctly. Thanks for the help. It directed me to learn more about defining type methods. I'm not sure what you mean exactly about thread safety in this case, but maybe I should read more about that too :)

Comment: @peacetype Since you'r starting and stopping the timer which is an instance variable. If multiple threads try to do this at the same time, you might have problems.

Answer (score 1):

The function you have specified is not a class function. Add **class** keyword before **func** keyword.

The changed code:

```
class func cycleTimer
```

Note: In the previous versions of Swift you must use the following code (and also in C or other languages):

```
static func cycleTimer
```